# Get corresponding array values from same index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => UHGYTF
            [email_copy] => Email copy 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => HDEFGV
            [email_copy] => Email copy 2
        )

)
```

I am trying to get the value of 'email_copy' using the corresponding code value.

e.g. Entering '**HDEFGV**' should retrieve '**Email copy 2**'.

I have tried array_search, but i'm having problems due to being a multi dimentional array.

All help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any tryout code to show?

Comment: Sorrym @JustOnUnderMillions this is all i have

Comment: `function getValueByValue($value,$array,$lookupkey='code',$valuekey='email_copy'){
      foreach($array as $set){
       if($set[$lookupkey]==$value){
        return $set[$valuekey];
       }
      }
     return null;
    }`